# Firebase Cloud Function returning wrong time

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The following code returns "10:50 PM" when run in Chrome or Firefox:

```
new Date(1572148200000).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: true, timeZone: 'America/Chicago' })
```

However, when I use the exact same code in a Cloud Function and have it sent to me as a text, it returns "3:50 AM". How do I get the server to return the same time as the browser? I assume this is a timezone issue, but I'm using `toLocaleTimeString` and explicitly setting it to my `timeZone`, so the discrepancy between the browser and server is confusing me.

Comment: You should never store a localTIme in your server! You should let the client side handle the timezone!

Comment: My database is storing dates in UTC and my browser is handling the timezone. I don't have any problems with how dates display in the browser. My issue is when my Cloud Function sends a text message that includes the time.

Comment: Well your cloud function should send time in UTC. And then your browser handles the timezone

Comment: @Melchia presumably the user isn't reading text/sms messages with a browser.

Comment: @Brett I can't reproduce this in a HTTP cloud function that just returns the string as its only output  (it returns "10:50 PM" for me) -- but I am not trying to send a text, just render the string.  I am using the Node 8 environment.  Can you give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?